# operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (16,) (21,) -pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have pandas pivot table datafrme "df_summary_table". print(df_summary_table) gives [16 rows x 21 columns]

```
    m1 = (df_summary_table.index == "test1")
    m2 = df_summary_table.columns.str.startswith('NA')
    df_summary_table.loc[m1 & m2] = 10
```

I am trying to perfoem above operation getting weired error.
`print(m1)` gives:

```
[ True False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False]
```

length of m1 is 16
`print(m2)` gives :

```
    [False False False False False False False False False False  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True False]
```

length of m2 is 21

both m1 and m2 are "" Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is there is no `Multiindex`, so need `m1` for filter rows and `m2` for filter columns, `"cost"` has to be removed and mask cannot be chained by `&`, because different lengths and different filtering (first filter per rows, second per columns):

```
df_summary_table.loc[m1, m2] = 10
```

Comment: I tried with the same but getting same error, edited the code snippet

Comment: @greenking - there is `,` between, no `&`